# Proof for proof $f(x)\leq f(0)e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f(0)>0$, $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\leq f(x)$ holds for all $x$. How can I prove $f(x)\leq f(0)e^x$ for $x$ in $[0,+\infty)$?

Making $df(t)/f(t)\leq dt$ and integrating from $0$ to $x$ is easy, but I can't get $df(t)/f(t)\leq dt$ since $f(t)$ can be negative for some intervals.

Comment: $\frac d {dx} (e^{-x}f(x))=e^{-x} (f'(x)-f(x)) \leq 0$. So $e^{-x}f(x)$ is a decreasing function and $e^{-x}f(x) \leq e^{-0}f(0)$ for $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 5):

We get
$$f'(x)e^{-x} \le f(x) e^{-x}$$
so
$$\int_0^x (f'(x)e^{-x} - f(x)e^{-x})dx \le 0$$
then
$$[f(x)e^{-x}]_0^x \le 0$$
ie. $f(x) \le f(0)e^{x}$.

Comment: Oh it's wonderful thx

Comment: @Kuroneko It's my pleasure ;)

Comment: Minor quibble: You're using $x$ in two different ways in the integral; it's better to write, e.g., $\int_0^xg(t)\,dt$ than $\int_0^xg(x)\,dx$.

Comment: One thing to note is that $f'$ might not be integrable [say, in the sense of Riemann].

Comment: If $\phi:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\phi’(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ in the sense of Lebesque, then $\int_a^x\phi’(t)dt=\phi(x)-\phi(a)\;$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. So, if $f’(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ in the sense of Lebesgue, the proof of Michelle is correct.